# How to use @Autowired in SpringBoot unit test

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-boot-test

I am trying to unit test (using JUnit5 jupiter) a class developed in Java with Spring Boot that I would like to use the @Autowired annotation for convenience.

A very simplified version of it is as follow:

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Demo {
    public String get() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;


@SpringJUnitConfig
class DemoTest {

    @Autowired private Demo sut;

    @Test
    void Test() {
        Assertions.assertEquals("hello", sut.get());
    }
}
```

When I run the test this error occurs:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.demo.DemoTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sut'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.Demo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:417)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
...
```

How to prevent it?
To be noted: for this test, I do not want to start the full application using @SpringBootTest

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually when you use `@ContextConfiguration` (which is a significant part of the stereotype `@SpringJUnitConfig` annotation) you should specify the configuration class from which the "Demo" component will be resolved.
Otherwise spring won't know which classes to load.

So you should basically create a configuration class (annotated with `@Configuration`) And specify what do you want to load there, for example with `@ComponentScan`

Haven't tested it but something like this should work:

```java
@SpringJUnitConfig(MyTestConfig.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired Demo sut;

    public void test() {... sut.doSomething(...); ...}
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(...) // here you should specify how to 
                    // load the Demo class and maybe other classes as well
public class MyTestConfig {

}
```

Of course if instead of `@Component` you already use Java Config and define `Demo` class there you won't need to create this auxiliary `MyTestConfig` class and can load the configuration with the `Demo` class right away

Comment: Indeed, it is working with the configuration class. Thanks. Is there a way not have to specify this configuration class? Maybe by using annotation other than @SpringJUnitConfig ?

Comment: I don't think you can make it working without the configuration class, it can be an inner class in the MyTest but in general spring has to know where to load the beans from and this is exactly what the configuration class does...