# Include Spring Security beans in JUnit tests Application Context

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a class `ToServiceFactory` which has an attribute `List<ToService<?>> toServices` which gets injected by Spring based on all the `@Service` classes implementing ToService:

```java
public class ToServiceFactory {

    private final List<ToService<?>> toServices;

    @Autowired
    public ToServiceFactory(List<ToService<?>> toServices) {
        this.toServices = List.copyOf(toServices);
    }
    // ...
}
```

I have a unit test that verifies that this factory works properly. Since the factory relies on Spring populating the list of toServices properly, I'm using `@SpringJUnitConfig` to run my test:

```java
@SpringJUnitConfig(Application.class)
class ToServiceFactoryTest {

    private final ToServiceFactory serviceFactory;

    @Autowired
    ToServiceFactoryTest(ToServiceFactory serviceFactory) {
        this.serviceFactory = serviceFactory;
    }
    /// My unit tests below ...
}
```

This has been working properly until now where I've added some functionalities related to `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`. In particular, I've added a configuration class to configure a WebClient:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction filter =
                new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        return WebClient.builder().apply(filter.oauth2Configuration()).build();
    }
}
```

Now, when I try to run my unit test, it fails because it cannot find a OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager bean to autowire:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I guess that to have it work, I need to find a way for the oauth beans to be available in my unit test ApplicationContext but I don't know how to do that.
I tried running the test with `@SpringBootTest` instead and it worked but ideally I'd like not to load the full application for my test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define bean OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager in WebClientConfig class, here is a default definition:

```
@Bean
OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

  OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
      .authorizationCode()
      .refreshToken()
    .build();
DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
  clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

return authorizedClientManager;
}
```

[This](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-auth-server) could be helful for more details.

If you don't want to updated your code just to make test works. you can add this beans manually on a test configuration like [this](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-init-a-bean-for-testing/). [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72898885/how-to-use-autowired-in-springboot-unit-test) could be also useful.

Comment: My production code works properly without this. It only starts failing when running unit tests, I believe because these beans are created by Spring Boot somehow. So ideally I wouldn't want to modify my production code to solve this.

Comment: I understand. a work arround would be to add this bean just for tests.  I updated this answer about that